How to decrypt ZTE F6600P router's encrypted “config.bin” file?
I have a ZTE F6600P (Software Version V9.0.10) router provided by my ISP, and I'm trying to retrieve certain credentials stored in the configuration.
Previously, with a different router, I could download the config.xml file directly from the web interface and extract the needed information. However, with this new router, the backup file is in an encrypted config.bin format.
So far, I've tried the following:
Downloaded the config.bin file from the router's web interface.
Used tools like the ZTE config utility, but the router appears to use a newer encryption algorithm (payload type 6), which isn't supported by the tools I've found.
I tried to use the serial number as an encryption key, without success.
Telnet and SSH ports are closed, and there is no option to enable them from the web interface.
Flashing custom firmware could be a last resort, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.
Can someone help me decrypt the config.bin file, or suggest any tools that work with newer ZTE models?

Here is the bad news. Type 6 is encryption which means you need the password to decrypt the configuration file, and Type 6 is “difficult”, rated by the NSA. The chances that the serial is part of the salt with a uniformed password is very high but there isn’t any guarantee that’s the case. My suggestion get your own hardware if your ISP allows it.

If you don’t even have telnet then you can’t even do what this individual did [here] but even if you did type 5 is significantly less secure then type 6

So having shell access to the router is a must, but after getting access how can I recover the unencrypted config can you clarify more.
